# Rescaling variables in a derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a derivative that looks like $\frac{dg}{dt}$, and I want to "rescale" it to be in the form $\frac{dx}{d\tau}$.  I know that $g=\alpha x$, where $\alpha$ is a constant, and can let $\tau$ be anything I choose.  So my question is, am I allowed to rewrite things in the following manner:

$\frac{dg}{dt}=\frac{d(\alpha x)}{dt}=\frac{\alpha dx}{dt} = \frac{dx}{\frac{1}{\alpha}dt} = \frac{dx}{d(\frac{t}{\alpha})} = \frac{dx}{d \tau}$, where $\tau = \frac{t}{\alpha}$? Are these legal operations? Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes, you are doing good (but you mean, $\tau = \frac{t}{\alpha}$, right?)

Comment: yes, of course silly mistake I've edited my original question to show that.  Thanks for confirming for me

Answer (score 2):

It's fine (as long as $\alpha \neq 0$, of course)